# Call arguments in a function in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab

I tried to run this function in MATLAB:

```
function llik = log_likelihood(p)
global d;
N = length(d);
tau = fzero(@(t) (t - (t^2 * p + 1 - p) / (2 * (t * p + 1 - p))), [0,1]);

loglik = 0;
for i = 1 : N
    loglik = loglik + log(isnan(d(i)) * (1 - p * (1 - tau) + ~isnan(d(i))* p * (1 - tau)));
end

llik = loglik / N;
end
```

Here, p is a scalar. MATLAB gives me an error warning saying

```
Error using fzero>localFirstFcnEval
FZERO cannot continue because user-supplied function_handle ==>
@(t)(t-(t^2*p+1-p)/(2*(t*p+1-p))) failed with the error below.

 Unrecognized function or variable 'p'.
```

I am confused since p should be the argument of the function. How can it be unrecongized? Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: Hi Cris. I call the function by `p = 0.85; log_likelihood (p)`

Comment: Then this should work. The only explanation for errors would be that you have overridden standard MATLAB functions (don’t create M-files with names matching standard MATLAB functions) or that you’re calling a different function than you think (use `which log_likelihood` to see which function you’re actually calling).

Comment: Hi Cris. Thank you again for your reply! I have tried your advice and found that `log_likelihood` is the one in my current folder. The same error is reported.

Answer (score -1):

Everything seems okay with my Matlab if i assign the value d **inside the function**, where do you define the variable `d`, if it's a global variable, it must be define as:

```
global d;
```

This is my result:

[image: result with assign d variable]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think I made a mistake in my code. My code did define the global variable `d`, which is a vector. I have modified the question to correct the mistake. However, it seems that it still does not work.

Comment: in your code, do you write `global d` outside `log_likelihood`? or do you really declare 1st time global d inside `log_likelihood`?

Comment: I have defined the vector `d` outside the function. `global d` is defined first time in side `log_likelihood`

Comment: Type `disp(d)` and `disp(p)` inside your function, before defining the anonymous function. Then you can make sure your variables have the values you think they do. You can do the same thing using the debugger, which is 100% worth while to learn to use. MATLAB docs on debugging are good, go read them!